# Google Recaptcha Validation ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl mycaptcha = (Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RecaptchaControl1");
    mycaptcha.Validate();
    Boolean answer = mycaptcha.IsValid;
    if (answer == false)
    {
        ((CancelEventArgs)e).Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Hi above is my code for Validating Google Recapture, I am using a `CreateUserWizard` form on Visual Studio.

The code is fine until I run it and an error appears stating

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_whsxk5eb.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

for the line `mycaptcha.Validate();`

I'm not sure how to fix it.